# cmder: why can't I use ALT+TAB to navigate to it?

Tags: cmder

I am using `cmder`with Windows 7. Two git-bash tabs.

I started `cmder` and cannot see it in `ALT+TAB`. Is there any config I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

cmder is just a bundle of ConEmu, config and some third party tools. First you need to do is updating ConEmu to latest preview or alpha build.

ConEmu is not visible in <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> list if you hide it from TaskBar (Settings >> Task bar >> Taskbar buttons).

Mostly it's used with Quake mode when you access ConEmu by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> or other fast access hotkey.